# what is the difference between udf from SparkSession and udf from pyspark.sql.functions

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have two ways to use `udf` in pyspark:

1.

```
spark = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
print(spark.udf)
output:
<pyspark.sql.udf.UDFRegistration at 0x7f5532f823a0>
```

2. 

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
print(udf)
output:
<function pyspark.sql.functions.udf(f=None, returnType=StringType)>
```

I do not understand what is the intended difference between the two. I get doubts like why are two APIs available.`spark.udf` has a method called register available with it. I think registering a `udf` is necessary. Then, why is it not available in `pyspark.sql.functions`. Why is it needed only for the first case?

Can you please help me clarify these doubts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`spark.udf.register` is used to register UDF to be invoked in Spark SQL query. While `pyspark.sql.functions.udf` is used to create UDF to be called when using DataFrame API.

###### Register UDF and use with SQL

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import LongType

df = spark.range(1, 5)
df.createOrReplaceTempView("tb")

def plus_one(v):
    return v + 1

spark.udf.register("plus_one_udf", plus_one, LongType())

spark.sql("select id, plus_one_udf(id) as id2 from tb").show()
#+---+---+
#| id|id2|
#+---+---+
#|  1|  2|
#|  2|  3|
#|  3|  4|
#|  4|  5|
#+---+---+
```

###### Using with DataFrame API

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

plus_one_udf = F.udf(plus_one, LongType())

df.withColumn("id2", plus_one_udf(F.col("id"))).show()

#+---+---+
#| id|id2|
#+---+---+
#|  1|  2|
#|  2|  3|
#|  3|  4|
#|  4|  5|
#+---+---+
```

Comment: And why is it that only one needs to be registered?

Comment: @MiloMinderbinder What do you mean by "_only one_"?

Comment: you called register only on one udf: ```spark.udf.register("plus_one_udf", plus_one, LongType())```. I am wondering why such semantics are not needed for pyspark.sql.functions.udf

Comment: @MiloMinderbinder you need to call `spark.udf.register` in order to register the UDF in your spark session and thus be able to invoke it when using SQL. And no, `spark.udf.register` can also take `pyspark.sql.functions.udf` function. You can test it yourself `spark.udf.register("plus_one_udf", plus_one_udf)` where `plus_one_udf` is the UDF defined using `F.udf(...)`.